# How does this conditional statement work?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

This function finds the middle value of an array. But the conditional statement makes no sense to me, since `arr.length === 0` is never true but the function still works for both even and odd numbers. I think the condition should be `arr.length % 2 !== 0` and it works too, but even then I don't see how the correct value is returned, since for an array of 1-13, the function would return the Math.floor of 13/2 = 6.5 which is 6, but it returns 7. And for an array 1-12 it would return the Math.ceil of (12-1)/2 = 5.5 which is also 6, but again it returns 7, which is what it's supposed to do but I don't see how the conditional statements produce this result.

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
// if even, the number closer to end is returned

function findMiddle(arr) {
   return arr.length === 0 ? arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)]
   : arr[Math.ceil((arr.length - 1) / 2)];
}

console.log(findMiddle(x))
```

Comment: "Math.ceil of (12-1)/2 = 5.5 which is also 6, but again it returns 7" 6 is the array index, 7 is the value. That's correct, `arr[6] = 7` (Arrays in JavaScript are zero-based)

Comment: Oh, i can't believe i missed that. So that answers that question, but what about ````arr.length === 0```` ? Why does that conditional statement give the same result?

Comment: you mean the ternary operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: `arr.length === 0` is only ever true when you pass an empty array, and it will then throw an error. I believe what would be best in this case would be for it to be: `arr.length === 0 ? null : ...` or something similar to indicate that the request for the middle element was invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the condition is always false, this function will always return the first value which is `arr[Math.ceil((arr.length - 1) / 2)]` which is always correct I assume.

- For the first example (an array from 1 - 13): `arr.length` is `13`, arr.length / 2 will be `6.5`, then `Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)` will be `7` and finally `arr[Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)]` will result in `arr[7]` which is `8`
- For the second example (an array from 1 - 12): `arr.length` is `12`, arr.length / 2 will be `6`, then `Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)` will be `6` and finally `arr[Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)]` will result in `arr[6]` which is `7`.

**Conclusion:** The condition is not doing anything there. It's completely useless if you always provide it with non-empty arrays. Your function, in that case, will be simply:

```
function findMiddle(arr) {
   return arr[Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)]
}
```

And it will give the same results.

Comment: The condition is always false, so the function returns the second value (`arr[Math.ceil((arr.length - 1) / 2)]`) not the first

Comment: You're right guys! Thanks for bringing it up! I thought it was a `!==` and not a `===`. I edited my response. I think it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

If arr has no elements, this function returns `arr[0]` which does not exist, so it throws an error. (edit: this would happen in any other language, but javascript being javascript actually returns undefined)

For an even number of elements, it returns the second of the two middle-elements.

For an uneven number of elements it returns the middle one.

In your example, it returns the element at index 6. This element is has the value 7.

Comment: But how does the function know when there are even or odd numbers? How does it know which of the two operations to perform since the conditional statement doesn't specify that and doesn't even make sense at all?

Comment: It doesn't know it, but subtracting one, dividing by two and then using `Math.ceil` will have different effects on even and odd numbers.